# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qgafa8x3/numba/

Tags: python, pip

> You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 21.2.1 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I have tried to resolve this error by using `pip install --upgrade setuptools` and `pip install --upgrade pip --user` but no success.
Please help me resolve this. Its occurring while executing the `sam build` command. Also, my python version is equal to 3.7 still its giving `RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.7 required`

Comment: 1) Have you tried `pip install –upgrade pip` ? 2) Are you using any virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. No but I'm using `sam init` and then deploying my code using docker and aws sam functionalities.

Comment: Is there any error traceback when you try running `pip install –upgrade pip` ?

Comment: When I first ran this command it gave this `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\hasan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-uninstall-5k7tv0av\\pip.exe'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.`   But now when I'm trying to execute this command its saying requirement already satisfied.

Comment: I think you might have conflicts in `pip` installation. You might have installed it with admin privilegies, and your Python installation is not, or vice versa. Can't tell.. My suggestion is: use a virtual environment and avoid conflicts like this.

Comment: Okay then, I'll try with it. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+EnvironmentError%3A+WinError+5+Access+is+denied+pip.exe